# How do I check to see if this method has been called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How do I check to see if this method has been called (or if the state is true perhaps)?

```
 [self.view addSubview:menu];
```

I need to write a conditional statement that tests to see if this is true or not:

```
[self.view addSubview:menu];
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is menu a view?

so,

```
if (menu.superview == self.view)
```

would test if menu has been added as desired

Answer (score 2):

```
if(menu.superview == aSpecificView)
// if true then menu is added as subview
```

if you want to check specific view then do this

```
if(menu.superview==aSpecificView)
 //do code here
```

Comment: I tried this but the darkBG doesn't display. the menu is displayed on the view too and I tested it with an NSLog statement :     [self.view addSubview:menu];
    
    if (menu.superview) {
        NSLog(@"menu view is added ");

        darkBG.hidden = NO;
    }

Comment: i did this jst to check if menu has any superview. if you want to check specific view then do this if(menu.superview==aSpecificView)

Comment: @TheSaad: You missed out on the answer by a small margin. That is because you didn't write the complete code. Add more descriptions to your answers. :)